# problem with setting up proxy - ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, proxy

I have spent a lot of time to solve a error in setting up proxy for JS API but I could not find any solution.

I did following steps:

1. I downloaded the proxy files for .Net.
2. I edited proxy.config file
3. I created an application
4. i tested proxy

when i run my codes it gives following error in chrome browser:

> proxy.ashx?http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/sdeMXD/MapServer?f=json&dpi=96&transparent=tr…:1
>
> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

in firebug it gives this error:

> GET http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/info?f=json 200 OK 87ms/3.16/
>   (line152)
>
> **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'**     proxy.a...allback (line 1) dojo.io.script error RequestTimeoutError: Timeout exceeded {
>   message="Timeout exceeded", 
>   stack=".cache["dojo/errors/crea...cgis.com/3.16/:204:284\n", 
>   response={...},  more...}

Comment: Do you have a stray "<" in your proxy.config file?

Comment: this is my proxy.config file , does it need any edit?                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*"
             mustMatch="true">
    <serverUrls>
        <serverUrl url="http://localhost:6080"
                   matchAll="true"/>
        
    </serverUrls>
</ProxyConfig>

Comment: sorry it is too messy, i could not find out how to attach proxy.config file

Comment: So that error seems to be a generic error thrown when you are trying to access a service without a valid token, usually caused by bad URLs... as far as I can tell ... As an aside, it looks like you have a stray space in your esri.css link. That could be beefing you up - it breaks my apps

Comment: the dynamicMapServiceLayer service works correctly when i do not use proxy and there is not any error but when i add proxy scripts                           ( esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "proxy/proxy.ashx";
    esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;),                               the error appears. anybody can help me?

Comment: try https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/blob/master/DotNet/README.md test by pinging http://[yourmachine]/DotNet/proxy.ashx?ping